# Purchase order for VS purchase order of

Tags: meaning

When you are sending a PO to the supplier, should you use **purchase order for** or **purchase order of**?

Examples

- Here is a purchase order for thirty HDMI cables.
- Here is a purchase order of thirty HDMI cables.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Purchase+order+for%2C+purchase+order+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CPurchase%20order%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpurchase%20order%20of%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Use "for" in this case.

Comment: @ P.E. Dant,  I think you are  right  There's something wrong with Ngram.

Comment: @Khan The complement of the copula is the noun "order," and it is idiomatic to prefer "order _for_" when talking about buying things. (If the complement were "purchase," it would be idiomatic to use "of:" _"I'm inquirimg about the purchase **of** thirty HDMI cables."_)

Comment: @Khan It's an interesting distinction. In business, we say "purchase order _for,_" but we use "of" when referring to the actual transaction. "Purchase order" connotes the physical form used to initiate the transaction, while "order" talks about the transaction itself. (I think.)

Comment: My pleasure, @Khan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> a purchase order

is paperwork used to "buy *something*", so it is "**for** *something*" and not "of *something*".

> Q: Do you have the purchase order *for* the shipment *of* HDMI cables?
>   A: Here is a purchase order *for* the purchase *of* HDMI cables.